# How to set same identation for `tabular`'s on different, but successive, pages?

Tags: tables, indentation, tabularx

> How to set same identation for `tabular`'s on different, but successive, pages?

I've two `tabular`'s, each on different, but successive, pages of the document.

To have same identation, I've tried the `\noindent`, but this doesn't seem to help.

As can be seen on the image, the identation are slightly different.

What mechanism can I use to get same indentation?

[image]

```
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}[h]{rlrrl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{30s: Environmental Information}} \vspace{5pt} \\
\textbf{Value} & \textbf{Mnemonic} & $\delta$ & $\alpha$ & \textbf{Description} \vspace{5pt} \\
0x30 & {ADDRESS} & 0 & 1 & Get address of currently executing account. \\
0x31 & {BALANCE} & 1 & 1 & Get balance of the given account. \\
0x32 & {ORIGIN} & 0 & 1 & Get execution origination address. \\
0x33 & {CALLER} & 0 & 1 & Get caller address. \\
0x34 & {CALLVALUE} & 0 & 1 & Get deposited value by the instruction/transaction. \\
0x35 & {CALLDATALOAD} & 1 & 1 & Get input data of current environment. \\
0x36 & {CALLDATASIZE} & 0 & 1 & Get size of input data in current environment. \\
0x37 & {CALLDATACOPY} & 3 & 0 & Copy input data in current environment to memory. \\
0x38 & {CODESIZE} & 0 & 1 & Get size of code running in current environment. \\
0x39 & {CODECOPY} & 3 & 0 & Copy code running in current environment to memory. \\
0x3a & {GASPRICE} & 0 & 1 & Get price of gas in current environment. \\
0x3b & {EXTCODESIZE} & 1 & 1 & Get size of an account's code. \\
0x3c & {EXTCODECOPY} & 4 & 0 & Copy an account's code to memory. \\
\end{tabular*}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}[h]{rlrrl}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{40s: Block Information}} \vspace{5pt} \\
\textbf{Value} & \textbf{Mnemonic} & $\delta$ & $\alpha$ & \textbf{Description} \vspace{5pt} \\
0x40 & {BLOCKHASH} & 1 & 1 & Get the hash of one of the 256 most recent complete blocks. \\
0x41 & {COINBASE} & 0 & 1 & Get the block's beneficiary address. \\
0x42 & {TIMESTAMP} & 0 & 1 & Get the block's timestamp. \\
0x43 & {NUMBER} & 0 & 1 & Get the block's number. \\
0x44 & {DIFFICULTY} & 0 & 1 & Get the block's difficulty. \\
0x45 & {GASLIMIT} & 0 & 1 & Get the block's gas limit. \\
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Is your document two-sided?

Comment: @samcarter - yes,  why?

Comment: @Shuzheng Then I would guess your current behaviour is normal, as a two-sided document normally has asymmetric margins to allow space for binding etc.

Comment: @Shuzheng Just for fun, try to with the option `oneside` and have a look if the position of the table is now the same.

Comment: @samcarter - what does twoside actually do?

Comment: @Shuzheng a couple of things, but relevant for your problem: it adjusts the margins depending on if they are on the inside or outside of a page.